# Chrome crashes when attempt to screen share during Zoom session

Tags: google-chrome, crash

I've been using Zoom in the browser as the Zoom app does not support screen share on Wayland yet. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.
It worked fine until this week. Every time I attempt to screenshare the entire chrome session crashes. I thought it was due to the OOM killer in 22.04, but my RAM usage has not gone up to even 25% during the Zoom session.
`journalctl -b -u systemd-oomd` does not show any process being killed either. Any idea how I can debug this?

Comment: can you run the browser from a terminal (`google-chrome`), and see what errors come up?

Comment: Ah yes thank you. I was able to see the error logs and figured out that it is due to the problem described [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/2464). For anyone who are curious, the solution is to downgrade `xdg-desktop-portal-wlr`. However, I have since switched to Firefox which works out of the box.