# Zoom does not respond when I share the screen

Tags: 22.04, freeze, wayland, zoom-meeting

I have problems with the Zoom screen sharing: when I share the screen zoom freezes, my image appears black to those connected to the same meeting and I cannot click on stop sharing since the sharing option panel doesn't appear.

I have tried to adopt solutions from other questions.
For example I tried to disable the gpu via the command:

`zoom-client  --disable-gpu-sandbox`

I have also deselected from Video/Advanced both "`Optimize video quality with de-noise`" and "`Use hardware acceleration for receiving video`" but the outcome is the same as above.

In some questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423668/chrome-crashes-when-attempt-to-screen-share-during-zoom-session), people associate this kind of problem with Wayland.

My Ubuntu release is 22.04.

Comment: Use xorg instead of wyland.

Comment: @Pilot6 Could you please describe the entire procedure related to the installation of xorg on the answer panel below? I would appreciate that.

Comment: At the login screen press the "gear" and select xorg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known problem that Zoom can't share desktop when using `wayland`.

While logging in click the gear at the right bottom of your screen and select "Xorg".